# scrapy: Call a function when a spider quits

Tags: python, scrapy

Is there a way to trigger a method in a Spider class just before it terminates?

I can terminate the spider myself, like this:

```
class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    #Config stuff goes here...

    def quit(self):
        #Do some stuff...
        raise CloseSpider('MySpider is quitting now.')

    def my_parser(self, response):
        if termination_condition:
            self.quit()

        #Parsing stuff goes here...
```

But I can't find any information on how to determine when the spider is about to quit naturally.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

It looks like you can register a signal listener through `dispatcher`.

I would try something like:

```
from scrapy import signals
from scrapy.xlib.pydispatch import dispatcher

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    def __init__(self):
        dispatcher.connect(self.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)

    def spider_closed(self, spider):
      # second param is instance of spder about to be closed.
```

---

In the newer version of scrapy `scrapy.xlib.pydispatch` is deprecated. instead you can use from `pydispatch import dispatcher`.

Comment: Works perfectly.  But I'd suggest naming the method MySpider.quit() or something similar, to avoid confusion with the signal name.  Thanks!

Comment: Excellent solution. And yes, the example should work exactly the same with a `CrawlSpider`.

Comment: This solution also work fine on Scrapy **0.20.0**, contrary to what @Chris said below.

Comment: This solution also work fine on Scrapy 0.24.4, contrary to what @Chris said below.

Comment: I'm confused by why the second parameter of spider_closed is necessary.  Isn't the spider to be closed self?

Comment: Doesn't work with v. 1.1 because xlib.pydispatch was deprecated. Instead, they recommend to use PyDispatcher. Though couldn't make it work yet...

Comment: Fabolous! This is exactly what I was looking for! And works perfectly fine! Great input mate! And thanks :3

Comment: This *still* works in `Python 3.6.4`, with `Scrapy 1.5.1` and using `PyDispatcher 2.0.5`, and even if you also have a `def spider_closed(..)` in some pipeline *Class* in your `pipelines.py`. However, it is also **deprecated** as shown [here](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/1762), so use the *new* method as explained by @Levon.

Comment: In the newer version of scrapy `scrapy.xlib.pydispatch` is deprecated. insted of this you can use `from pydispatch import dispatcher`

Answer (score 65):

Just to update, you can just call [`closed`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html?highlight=closed#scrapy.spiders.Spider.closed) function like this:

```
class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    def closed(self, reason):
        do-something()
```

Comment: In my scrapy it's `def close(self, reason):`, not `closed`

Comment: @AminahNuraini Scrapy 1.0.4 `def closed(reason)`

Answer (score 19):

For Scrapy version **1.0.0+** (it may also work for older versions).

```
from scrapy import signals

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'myspider'

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler, *args, **kwargs):
        spider = super(MySpider, cls).from_crawler(crawler, *args, **kwargs)
        crawler.signals.connect(spider.spider_opened, signals.spider_opened)
        crawler.signals.connect(spider.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)
        return spider

    def spider_opened(self, spider):
        print('Opening {} spider'.format(spider.name))

    def spider_closed(self, spider):
        print('Closing {} spider'.format(spider.name))
```

One good usage is to add [tqdm](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm) progress bar to scrapy spider.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from scrapy import signals
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from tqdm import tqdm


class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'myspider'
    allowed_domains = ['somedomain.comm']
    start_urls = ['http://www.somedomain.comm/ccid.php']

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r'^http://www.somedomain.comm/ccds.php\?id=.*'),
             callback='parse_item',
             ),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r'^http://www.somedomain.comm/ccid.php$',
                           restrict_xpaths='//table/tr[contains(., "SMTH")]'), follow=True),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        self.pbar.update()  # update progress bar by 1
        item = MyItem()
        # parse response
        return item

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler, *args, **kwargs):
        spider = super(MySpider, cls).from_crawler(crawler, *args, **kwargs)
        crawler.signals.connect(spider.spider_opened, signals.spider_opened)
        crawler.signals.connect(spider.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)
        return spider

    def spider_opened(self, spider):
        self.pbar = tqdm()  # initialize progress bar
        self.pbar.clear()
        self.pbar.write('Opening {} spider'.format(spider.name))

    def spider_closed(self, spider):
        self.pbar.clear()
        self.pbar.write('Closing {} spider'.format(spider.name))
        self.pbar.close()  # close progress bar
```

Comment: This is the **new** method! Although it look less transparent, it's advantage is to remove the extra clutter of using: `def __init__(self):..` and the PyDispatcher import with `from scrapy.xlib.pydispatch import dispatcher`.

Answer (score 12):

For the latest version(v1.7), just define `closed(reason)` method in your spider class.

> `closed(reason)`:
>
> Called when the spider closes. This method provides a shortcut to
> signals.connect() for the spider_closed signal.

[Scrapy Doc : scrapy.spiders.Spider.closed](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Spider.closed)

Answer (score 7):

For me the accepted did not work / is outdated at least for scrapy 0.19.
I got it to work with the following though:

```
from scrapy.signalmanager import SignalManager
from scrapy.xlib.pydispatch import dispatcher

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MySpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        SignalManager(dispatcher.Any).connect(
            self.closed_handler, signal=signals.spider_closed)

    def closed_handler(self, spider):
        # do stuff here
```

Answer (score 1):

if you have many spiders and want to do something before each of them closing, maybe it will be convenient to add statscollector in your project.

in settings:

```
STATS_CLASS = 'scraper.stats.MyStatsCollector'
```

and collector:

```
from scrapy.statscollectors import StatsCollector

class MyStatsCollector(StatsCollector):
    def _persist_stats(self, stats, spider):
        do something here
```