# Where and how to print scrapy stats upon spider_closed signal (finish)?

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a working *BaseSpider* on Scrapy **0.20.0**. But I'm trying to collect the number of found website URL's and print it as INFO when the spider is finished (closed). Problem is that I am not able to print this simple integer variable at the *end of the session*, and any print statement in the `parse()` or `parse_item()` functions are printed too early, long before.

I also looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12394184/scrapy-call-a-function-when-a-spider-quits) question, but it seem somewhat outdated and it is unclear how to use it, properly. I.e. Where to put it (myspider.py, pipelines.py etc)?

Right now my spider-code is something like:

```
class MySpider(BaseSpider):
...
foundWebsites = 0
...
def parse(self, response):
    ...
    print "Found %d websites in this session.\n\n" % (self.foundWebsites)

def parse_item(self, response):
    ...
    if item['website']:
        self.foundWebsites += 1
    ...
```

And this is obviously not working as intended. Any better and simple ideas?

Comment: Why don't you use the stats extension? `self.crawler.stats.inc_value('found_websites')`.

Comment: Because I'm counting collected items (preferably unique) and not crawled sites. You could imagine, replacing "website" by "email" or some other field, that may not even be present. (That's why I want to count them!) I guess one should be able to use the `spider_closed` signal, but I have no idea how to use it.

Comment: what holds you from simply copy and paste the code from the answer you referred to your spider?

Comment: I suppose a misinterpretation of the 2nd answer, thinking that the 1st answer was outdated. I just tried the 1st and darn it, it works! I apologize for excessive posting and I will add a comment there.

Answer (score 1):

The first answer [referred to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12394184/scrapy-call-a-function-when-a-spider-quits) works and there is no need to add anything else to pipelines.py. Just add "that answer" to your spider code like this:

```
# To use "spider_closed" we also need:
from scrapy.xlib.pydispatch import dispatcher
from scrapy import signals

class MySpider(BaseSpider):
...
foundWebsites = 0
...
def parse(self, response):
    ...

def parse_item(self, response):
    ...
    if item['website']:
        self.foundWebsites += 1
    ...

def __init__(self):
    dispatcher.connect(self.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)

def spider_closed(self, spider):
    if spider is not self:
        return
    print "Found %d websites in this session.\n\n" % (self.foundWebsites)
```