# selenium:socket.error: [Errno 61] Connection refused

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, scrapy

There are 10 links I want to catch
When I run spider,I can get the links in json file ,but there are still errors like this:
It seems like selenium run twice.What's the problem is?
Please guide me Thank you

```
2014-08-06 10:30:26+0800 [spider2] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.test/a/1>
{'link': u'http://www.test/a/1'}
2014-08-06 10:30:26+0800 [spider2] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET
http://www.test/a/1>
Traceback (most recent call last):
 ........
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 571, in create_connection
    raise err
socket.error: [Errno 61] Connection refused
```

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from ta.items import TaItem
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from scrapy.http.request import Request

class ProductSpider(Spider):
    name = "spider2"  
    start_urls = ['http://www.test.com/']
    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

    def parse(self, response):
        self.driver.get(response.url)
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(20)  
        next = self.driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.body .heading a")
        for a in next:
            item = TaItem()    
            item['link'] =  a.get_attribute("href")     
            yield Request(url=item['link'], meta={'item': item}, callback=self.parse_detail)  

    def parse_detail(self,response):
        item = response.meta['item']
        yield item
        self.driver.close()
```

Comment: Why do you call `self.driver.close()` in `parse_detail()`?

Comment: I delete that line.And the error disappear.does it means I don't have to close it or where should I close it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you are closing the driver too early.

You should close it only when the spider finishes it work, listen to [`spider_closed`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/signals.html#spider-closed) signal:

```
from scrapy import signals
from scrapy.xlib.pydispatch import dispatcher
from selenium import webdriver
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from ta.items import TaItem
from scrapy.http.request import Request


class ProductSpider(Spider):
    name = "spider2"  
    start_urls = ['http://www.test.com/']
    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        dispatcher.connect(self.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)

    def parse(self, response):
        self.driver.get(response.url)
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(20)  
        next = self.driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.body .heading a")
        for a in next:
            item = TaItem()    
            item['link'] =  a.get_attribute("href")     
            yield Request(url=item['link'], meta={'item': item}, callback=self.parse_detail)  

    def parse_detail(self,response):
        item = response.meta['item']
        yield item

    def spider_closed(self, spider):
        self.driver.close()
```

See also: [scrapy: Call a function when a spider quits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12394184/scrapy-call-a-function-when-a-spider-quits).