# scrapy: post some forms following scrapy finishing processing urls

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am using scrapy to scrape data from a member's only site. I perform login and scrape data successfully.

However, I now need to submit some forms on the site when scraping of data is finished. i.e: following all reading of data, I want to write some data to the site I am scraping (reading) data from.

My question is:

How do I get informed of scrapy finished processing all url scraping, so I can perform some form submissions?

I noticed a solution - see here ([scrapy: Call a function when a spider quits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12394184/scrapy-call-a-function-when-a-spider-quits)) but for some reason I cannot continue yielding more Requests in the self.spider_closed method as it is called over on those examples so I can do some write operations.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you cannot continue using the spider after `spider_closed` signal has been fired - it is too late, spider is already closed at the moment.

A better signal to use would be [`spider_idle`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/signals.html#spider-idle):

> Sent when a spider has gone idle, which means the spider has no
>   further:
>
> - requests waiting to be downloaded
> - requests scheduled
> - items being
>     processed in the item pipeline