# Queue to allow Scrapy Analysis

Tags: python, multithreading, queue, scrapy

I'm pretty much a scrapy (and python) newbie and I'm trying to figure out how to use scrapy and analyze the data from it all in one script.  The program creates a json and I want to open that json after the program has finished scraping.

What happens is that the program tries to open the json before scrapy has finished because the actual os command has been executed.  I believe the answer may be to use threads and queues but I am having trouble figuring out how these are implemented.  Here is my code:

```python
def crawl():
    os.system("scrapy crawl average_cur -o currency.json -t json")

    inFile=open('currency.json')
    data=json.load(inFile)
    print data


crawl()
```

Comment: that's weird, are you sure that it's trying to load the file before scrapy is finished? it doesn't make much sense, since `os.system` waits for it to finish. you can try using `subprocess.check_output` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think scrapy signals will do the trick, this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12394184/scrapy-call-a-function-when-a-spider-quits) might help or you could write and [extension](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/extensions.html) and from there you can do whatever operation you want to perform.

In the extension,the `spider_closed()` will help you to complete your task.

```
def spider_closed(self, spider):
   # perform your task here
```