# After a while scrapy stops crawling and yielding items but continues to run

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I've written some scrapy code that should be able to loop through a series of cities, go to the specific pages for those cities, grab all the data in a table on that page, and iterate through all of the pages of tables for that city.
My code runs, but after a while it seems to time out or something, and I start getting this in my logs:

```
2020-12-16 18:47:47 [yjs] INFO: Parsing table and getting job data for page url http://www.yingjiesheng.com/other-morejob-1372.html
2020-12-16 18:48:27 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 113 pages (at 2 pages/min), scraped 111 items (at 2 items/min)
2020-12-16 18:49:27 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 113 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 111 items (at 0 items/min)
2020-12-16 18:50:27 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 113 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 111 items (at 0 items/min)
2020-12-16 18:51:27 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 113 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 111 items (at 0 items/min)
2020-12-16 18:52:27 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 113 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 111 items (at 0 items/min)
```

This seems to occur at random points of time. The first time I ran it I started getting this after 66 pages. Below is my spider code:

```
URLROOT = "https://www.yingjiesheng.com/"
CITIES = {"beijing": "北京"}

class YjsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "yjs"

    def start_requests(self):
        # loop through cities and pass info
        for key, value in CITIES.items():
            self.logger.info('Starting requests for %s', key)
            url = URLROOT + str(key)
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url=url, callback=self.retrieve_tabsuffix, 
                meta={'city': key, 'city_ch': value},
                encoding='gb18030'
            )

    def retrieve_tabsuffix(self, response):
        city = response.meta['city']
        city_ch = response.meta['city_ch']

        morepages = response.xpath(
            '//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "mbth", " " ))]')
        morepage_html = morepages.css("a::attr(href)").get()
        if "-morejob-" in morepage_html:
            jobpage_one = f"{URLROOT}{city}-morejob-1.html"
        elif "list_" in morepage_html:
            jobpage_one = f"{URLROOT}{city}/list_1.html"
        yield response.follow(
            url=jobpage_one, 
            callback=self.retrieve_tabhtmls,
            meta={'city': city, 'city_ch': city_ch},
            encoding='gb18030')


    def retrieve_tabhtmls(self, response):
        city = response.meta['city']
        city_ch = response.meta['city_ch']
        self.logger.info('Encodings are %s, %s', encoding1, encoding2)

        # htmls
        listhtmls = response.xpath(
                '//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "clear", " " ))]').get()
 
        totalrecords = response.xpath(
            '//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "act", " " ))]').get()
        self.logger.info("totalrecords: %s", totalrecords)

        # identify the last page number
        listhtmls = listhtmls.split("a href=\"")
        for listhtml in listhtmls:
            if "last page" in listhtml:
                lastpagenum = re.findall(r"\d+", listhtml)[0]
        morejobpages = list(range(1, int(lastpagenum) + 1))
        self.logger.info("total number tables %s", lastpagenum)

        self.logger.info('Getting all table page URLs for %s', city)
        morejobpages_urls = [
                "http://www.yingjiesheng.com/{}/list_{}.html".format(city, i) for i in morejobpages]

        self.logger.info(morejobpages)
        yield from response.follow_all(
            urls=morejobpages_urls,
            callback=self.parse_tab,
            meta={'city': city, 'city_ch': city_ch,
                  'totalrecords': totalrecords},
            encoding='gb18030')
    

    def parse_tab(self, response):
        city = response.meta['city']
        city_ch = response.meta['city_ch']
        totalrecords = response.meta['totalrecords']
        self.logger.info('Parsing table and getting job data for page url %s', response.url)

        # table content
        tabcontent = response.xpath(
            '//*[(@id = "tb_job_list")]')
        # list of rows
        tabrows = tabcontent.css("tr.jobli").getall()

        item = YjsTable()
        item['table'] = tabrows
        item['time_scraped'] = datetime.datetime.now().strftime(
                "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
        item['city'] = city
        item['city_ch'] = city_ch
        item['totalrecords'] = totalrecords
        item['pageurl'] = response.url
        yield item
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54184403/scrapy-gets-stuck-crawling-a-long-list-of-urls) is the only other post I found that seems to be running into the same issue, but they are pulling from  a SQL database and I am not.

Does anyone know why scrapy would work for a while and then all of a sudden stop requesting pages and grabbing data, but continuing to run?

**EDIT: I re-ran with the DEBUG logging settings and got this:**

```
2020-12-17 10:35:47 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 41 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 39 items (at 0 items/min)
2020-12-17 10:35:49 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET http://www.yingjiesheng.com/app/job.php?Action=FullTimeMore&Location=guangzhou&Source=Other&Page=86> from <GET http://www.yingjiesheng.com/guangzhou-morejob-86.html>
2020-12-17 10:36:06 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET http://www.yingjiesheng.com/guangzhou-morejob-86.html> from <GET http://www.yingjiesheng.com/app/job.php?Action=FullTimeMore&Location=guangzhou&Source=Other&Page=86>
2020-12-17 10:36:24 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET http://www.yingjiesheng.com/app/job.php?Action=FullTimeMore&Location=guangzhou&Source=Other&Page=85> from <GET http://www.yingjiesheng.com/guangzhou-morejob-85.html>
```

So it seems like I'm getting redirected, but it's not successfully scraping the information from the redirect and then moves on to the next page. Does anyone have an idea of how you would have scrapy keep trying a page until it's successful? Or if there's a better way to deal with this?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to check the [logging settings](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/logging.html#logging-settings) so you can enable better logging for your situation, it would be simpler to just set  `LOG_LEVEL='DEBUG'` so you can see everything that's going on, it looks like it's set to 'INFO' right now.

Something that could be happening is that the spider keeps finding requests, but all of them are rejected, so they are not counted as "pages", they could be 404s, 503s, etc.

You could also have some pages with long timeouts, scrapy doesn't stop working as its nature is to be asynchronous, so logs could keep appearing, even though scrapy is waiting for a proper response.

You can also configure your scrapy project to work like this (never end and just keep on living), but from what you shared, it doesn't look to be that way. Still, it should be worth checking what your extensions, pipelines, and middlewares are doing so you are sure they are not interfering with your spider.

You can always kill the spider, but make sure it stops on its own, so it also returns some stats, which are very revealing on what happened during the execution.

Comment: Thank you! I re-ran with debug logging settings and it seems like I'm getting issues with 301 and 302 redirects.

Comment: @seagullnutkin I checked your update an now you got a totally different question (irrelevant to your original question), so I'd recommend maybe asking another question. And checking the problem, you need to do a lot of debugging to the site and understand it better to solve what you are getting

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my issue. As shown from the logs below, the links were throwing a 301 redirect to a different link, and then throwing a 302 and redirecting back to the original link. Then scrapy wasn't scraping the page because it was a duplicate request.

```
2020-12-17 10:35:49 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET http://www.yingjiesheng.com/app/job.php?Action=FullTimeMore&Location=guangzhou&Source=Other&Page=86> from <GET http://www.yingjiesheng.com/guangzhou-morejob-86.html>
2020-12-17 10:36:06 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET http://www.yingjiesheng.com/guangzhou-morejob-86.html> from <GET http://www.yingjiesheng.com/app/job.php?Action=FullTimeMore&Location=guangzhou&Source=Other&Page=86>
```

To resolve this, I added the argument `dont_filter=True` to my `response.follow_all()` call, so that duplicates don't get filtered out for requests made using that function call. I also added the below to my `settings.py` file for help with debugging:
`DUPEFILTER_DEBUG = True`

More answers for dealing with duplicate requests in scrapy can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23131283/how-to-force-scrapy-to-crawl-duplicate-url).