# Can't assign value to self variable python

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to append string to indexes array inside parse function but when i try to save it to .json became empty.

```
import scrapy
import json

class NewsBrief(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "briefs"
    indexes = []
    def start_requests(self):
        ids = []
        url = "url"

        with open('test_id.json') as json_data:
            ids = json.load(json_data)

        for i in ids:
            yield scrapy.http.FormRequest(url=url+str(i), callback=self.parse)

        #self index is empty here
        print(self.indexes)

        with open('data_briefs.json', 'w') as outfile:
            json.dump(self.indexes, outfile)

    def parse(self, response):
        sentence = ""
        for span in enumerate(response.xpath('//div[@class="newsread olnr"]/p/text()').getall()):
            sentence += str(span[1]).replace('\n', ' ').replace('\r', ' ')
        self.indexes.append(sentence)
```

Comment: are you even sure `parse` is getting called?

Comment: @Nullman it works, i have tried to print `indexes` array inside this function and it worked

Comment: `start_requests` is executed before `parse` so indexes are always empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable `self.indexes` will not be filled after cycle with Requests. The requests even not being done there.

If you don't want to use common export to file, you can put writing to file to function on spider close. Check details here: [scrapy: Call a function when a spider quits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12394184/scrapy-call-a-function-when-a-spider-quits)

You need to bind signal to function and write code there.